# Maven 3.8.1 How to direct dependencies in pom to the right location and not take the repo url from settings.xml

Tags: selenium, maven-3

I have a pom with dependencies like selenium-java, com.saucelabs etc. and repositories with url pointing to JFrog repos. For the artifactory in JFrog repo I have commented out the  block in `conf/settings.xml` since it is HTTP. And I have the repo listed in `.m2/settings.xml`.
I am running into this error when I run `mvn install`

`Could not resolve dependencies for project com.github.frameworkium:frameworkium-core:jar:4.0.0-BETA2-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:4.1.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:4.1.1: Could not transfer artifact org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:pom:4.1.1 from/to snapshots (http://xxx-xxx.xxx/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local)`

Before adding Jfrog repo url to settings.xml I was able to pull the dependencies successfully.
What should I change/add in settings.xml to pull all the dependencies such as selenium-java from the right location and the repositories from JFrog repo url.

Comment: The settings.xml file has to be located in your home directory `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` and **NOT** into `$HOME/.m2/repository/settings.xml`...

Comment: @khmarbaise sorry but I have edited the comment above. I have the settings file in .m2 and not repository. All the dependencies are getting pointed to the JFrog repo instead of its own. I am new to maven so not sure how to point the dependencies selenium-java/ jacoco/google/log4j etc its maven dependencies instead of JFrog.

Comment: If you uare using jfrog I suppose you are in a corporate environment where you have to use that...

Comment: Yes that is right. Does that mean I have to have all of selenium dependencies added to the repository too, which I am not sure I can.

Comment: If you repository does not provide the deps you need there is something wrong... The repo manager should be connected to the internet and that should work...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @khmarbaise. I was able to get the deps from its right location. I added central to point to maven repo and the other dependencies to point to Jfrog repo.

```
 <repository>
     <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
         <id>central-artifactory</id>
         <name>libs-release</name>
         <url>http://xxxx.xxx/artifactory/libs-releaselocal</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
         <snapshots />
         <id>snapshots-artifactory</id>
         <name>libs-snapshot</name>
         <url>http://xxxx.xxx/artifactory/libs-releaselocal</url>
 </repository>
 <repository>
         <id>central</id>
         <name>Central Repository</name>
         <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
         <layout>default</layout>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
  </repository>
```